# WP7 - Positioning AdControl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ads, expression-blend-4

Is there an easy way to position an AdControl inside of a Panorama? Right now, I can only get my AdControl to show if I set up my object tree like so:

```
Layout Root > Panorama > ...
            > AdControl1
```

That is, with both my Panorama and my AdControl as immediate children of LayoutRoot.

I only want to show my AdControl on the first PanoramaItem, but when I do this, it fail to render:

```
LayoutRoot > Panorama > PanoramaItem > StackPanel > ListBox
                                                  > AdControl
```

That is, I want my AdControl to be underneath my ListBox, stuck to the bottom of that PanoramaItem only. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The XAML, extra PanoramaItems omitted

**Working**

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Panorama control-->
        <controls:Panorama Title="bad religion">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="content">
                <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
                <ListBox x:Name="LyricsListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LyricsListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
        <my:AdControl AdUnitId="TextAd" ApplicationId="test_client" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,720,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
    </Grid>
```

**Not Working**

```
 <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Panorama control-->
        <controls:Panorama Title="bad religion">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="content">
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
                    <ListBox x:Name="LyricsListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LyricsListBox_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <my:AdControl AdUnitId="TextAd" ApplicationId="test_client" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,720,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>        
    </Grid>
```

Comment: We've used the ad control on panoramas without any issue.  It would help to see your XAML for the page.  It could be that the ListBox is pushing the adcontrol off the bottom of the page, so that you cannot see it.  Also, if the adcontrol is not configured correctly you may not see anything as it auto-collapses when there is no content to show.

Comment: @WaltRitscher: That's good to hear! I've updated my post with my current working and non working code. If it's something obvious, I apologize, I've only been doing Microsoft Development for a week now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot see the AdControl is due to your Margin settings.  You have

```
Margin="0,720,0,0"
```

That places the AdControl 720 pixels down from the top of its container, which in this case is the **StackPanel**, not the LayoutRoot grid.

That means that the AdControl is off screen.

In your sample code you can create a temporary fix by changing the margin to something like.

```
Margin="0,420,0,0"
```

but that is not a good long term solution.  You should consider docking or using mutiple rows in a grid.

Another consideration, if you are filling the listbox with lyrics.  Have you considered using a textblock with TextWrapping enabled?

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. Although, now my 'ad' is just a blank square, no longer displaying the 'Bing test ad' text. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you setting the size on the AdControl?  I believe the correct size in 480 x 80.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ListBox` is pushing the ad control off the bottom of the page as Walt Ritscher states it may be, an option would be to wrap it in a `DockPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` with `LastChildFill` set to true and the order of elements in it inverted (so that the `ListBox` is last and therefore fills the remaining space of the DockPanel instead of expanding the `StackPanel` to take up its full requested size).

That is, something like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" ...>
   <my:AdControl/>
   <ListBox/>
</DockPanel>
```

The reason why this may be happening is that `ListBox` sizes itself to fit the content (and `StackPanel` allows it to be whatever size it wishes to be, as opposed to `DockPanel` which will limit it - in this instance, on Windows you'd add a `ScrollViewer`, but I'm not sure what you'd do for Phone).

If that's the case, you should then see a truncated `ListBox` and the `AdControl` underneath. If not, does the `AdControl` display if it's on its own in the panorama, or above the `ListBox` in a stackpanel?

Comment: I tried using this tutorial to add in DockPanel (http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Using-DockPanel-in-WP7), and after adding a reference to the .dll, and adding the namespace, I am getting a `type DockPanel not found` error. And with a regular StackPanel, there is just nothing. Blank.

Comment: I got the DockPanel added, but it is still just blank.

`

Comment: Josh, are you saying the DockPanel is blank or the AdControl?